# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/kestrals/public_html/demo/wp-content/themes/kestral/project page.php on line 1

Tags: wordpress

I create wordpress custom theme and did some plugin customization 
i get error in template page and from index page
Template Page error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/kestrals/public_html/demo/wp-content/themes/kestral/project page.php on line 1

Index page error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/kestrals/public_html/demo/wp-content/themes/kestral/index.php on line 1

I dis activate the customize plugin and try to remove all function and query even in empty file still i got the error i install theme on two server on both server i got same error.

Comment: I test website that error show on template page and index page and both pages have no error all other pages working fine. Plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it at last
if some one get stuck in this type of error
it cause because of template name you mention in start of file
like

```html
<?php /*
* Template Name:Demo
*/
get_header();
?>
```

change it into

```html
<?php 
/* Template Name:Demo */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that encounters this error and the above solution fails, the problem probably might not be with your coding but a transfer error usually encountered while transferring via FTP. Just change the transfer type to Binary

Sometimes, issues occur with files becoming corrupt when uploading via FTP. When viewing the corrupted file through the browser, a parse error occurs.

This is typically caused by uploading files through FTP as ASCII file transfer type or auto. The "ASCII transfer type" will transfer the files as regular text files. The "Binary transfer type" will transfer the data in binary mode which handles the files as binary data instead of text data. Setting your FTP client to Binary will prevent your files from becoming corrupted through ftp transit.

The following steps will demonstrate how to change the transfer type from ASCII to Binary in Filezilla.

1. Open Filezilla
2. Click on Transfer in the menu tab
3. Click on Transfer type and choose Binary